# Why doesn't the axios response get saved in useState variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I've built a random photo displaying feature in react. 
the console says that the response is valid and it works, 
but the page breaks when I return `data`.

Where is the issue?
Thanks in advance!

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function RandomPhoto() {
  const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_KEY}`
  const [data, setData] = useState()
  
  const getPhoto = () => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data)
        console.log(response.data) // <------- works
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getPhoto()
  },[])
  
  console.log("XX" + data) // <---------- doesn't work, and following return() neither

  return (
    <div>
      <img href={data.urls.regular} alt={data.alt_description}/> 
      <p>Photo by {data.username} {data.name} from {data.location} - found on unsplash</p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default RandomPhoto
```

Comment: By the first render the state is still undefined ... so the error's are ....
you can use optional chain or check as `(data && data.length > 0) ? {return(<div>...</div>)} : null` - null or anything you feel

Comment: I thought the first render happens in the useEffect. By then ```setData``` already updated ```data```, didn't it?

Comment: No .. [you can read here for more info from docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/render-and-commit)

Comment: I don't get it. I am sorry

Comment: Initially component renders it has state of undefined in your case as you haven't provided any initial state... Then the effects run (useEffect) runs with a short intervals and between other effects ... You can read [Marks guide](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a bit, and it's working. I made it as an async function and changed the path of JSON object keys.

Please note the location data sometimes returns as null. So you have to render it conditionally.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const RandomPhoto = () => {
  const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_KEY}`;
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState('');

  const getPhoto = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        setImageData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPhoto();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <img src={imageData.urls?.regular} />
      <p>
        Photo by {imageData?.user?.username} {imageData?.user?.name} from{' '}
        {imageData?.location?.country} - found on unsplash
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RandomPhoto;
```

[image: Example Image]